# Change font size without box size changing

Tags: css

I've been trying to create a button which would have its font size increased if it's hovered. And it works, but the problem is that the box itself becomes bigger when the font becomes bigger. One solution could be to have a fixed height, but I need it to stay as `auto`.

But once the font size changes, the box height won't change automatically anymore and instead would stay the same size.

```css
#btn {
  width: 40%;
  /* setting a height would fix this, but it must be auto */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00A859;
  transition: font 0.5s ease-in;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#btn:hover {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Hover me!</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the line-height of the font size so it would stay the same even the font is change.

```css
#btn {
  width: 40%;
  /* setting a height would fix this, but it must be auto */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00A859;
  transition: font 0.5s ease-in;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

#btn:hover {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Hover me!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply, by adding `line-height: 20px;` to `#btn`

```css
#btn {
  width: 40%;
  /* setting a height would fix this, but it must be auto */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00A859;
  transition: font 0.5s ease-in;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#btn:hover {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Hover me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap it in a fixed size div? One way or another, it seems you'll need to fix a bounding container (either the button itself or a div).

Alternately, you can get a similar effect by increasing the font while simultaneously decreasing the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Thomas!

```css
#btn {
  width: 40%;
  /* setting a height would fix this, but it must be auto */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00A859;
  transition: font 0.5s ease-in;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

#btn:hover {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Hover me!</div>
```